# Azure Traffic Alerts

Tags: azure, traffic

I could not find any functionality at the Azure Website that would allow me to receive traffic alerts for example in case of a DoS attack? Did I miss something or that feature simply not there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already replied to your post on MSDN forums, but happy to reply here as well:

There are service dashboards that have RSS feeds for status of various Azure services in various Azure data centers:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/support/status/servicedashboard.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but neither of the links you've provided provides a solution to the problem.

Comment: Microsoft should buy that app and gives that service for free. It's depressing that Azure has no monitoring tools or detailed billing reports you can use to figure out how to scale your app.

Comment: @vtortola - Microsoft does provide detailed billing reports. However, there's no API currently that provides programmatic access to resource usage metering. Some usage may be tracked with perfermance counters and the management API. Other items, such as bandwidth consumption, are only available through the detailed monthly billing report.

Microsoft's System Center Operation Manager has a Windows Azure monitoring add-in that Microsoft developed and provides.

Comment: @David Makogon does that mean we can only see monthly traffic consumption at the end of the month and not at a daily basis? If that should be the case everyone (and by that I mean small ISVs and independend developers) using Azure would risk personal ruin.

Comment: As far as Microsoft providing "that service for free" - here's a link to the Windows Azure Application Monitoring Management Pack info and download link. And it's free: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usisvde/archive/2010/10/05/windows-azure-application-monitoring-management-pack-released.aspx . And as far as the AzureWatch: It's a penny per instance per hour, which is (in my opinion) very affordable and a fraction of the cost you'd put into developing your own monitoring solution.

Comment: @Oliver - Correct - the report is published monthly for your account, wich very detailed reporting on all usage (bandwidth per storage account, compute-hours per service account, etc.). There's no real-time or daily view of this information.

Comment: @David Makogon unbelievable. I mean for an independent developer that could mean that you look at the monthly bill and realize you are financially ruined by DDos.

Comment: @Oliver - I'm sorry but "risk personal ruin" ia really a stretch. You can easily approximate service bandwidth by tracking performance counters for IIS, WCF, network bytes, etc. Further, you can track blob storage consumption by keeping a running total every time you write to blob storage (or enumerate container contents periodically). There are things such as public blob bandwidth consumption that can't be programmatically measured; however, at $0.15 / GB for outbound bandwidth from blob storage, it would take considerable consumption to drive a company to ruin.

Comment: @Oliver - having said all that: I think the discussion of risk is outside the scope of this question and belongs in a separate forum or blob post.

Comment: @David Makogon sorry to disagree. Estimating cloud based hosting costs based on careful analysis is one thing, but accidents like Dos attacks executed by people who don't give a damn about your estimates is another. And not being able to react because your cloud provider is not able to come up with reports at reasonable intervals is just plain wrong and unacceptable.

Comment: Additionally, check out the newly released Metering Application Block - http://cnmb.codeplex.com/